# HapiJS/Joi Allow field to be String or Object with specific keys

Tags: node.js, joi

I'm trying to validate a POST request where the `title` can be a **String** or an **Object** with language keys and values. Example:

```
{
    title: 'Chicken',
    ...
}
//OR
{
    title: {
        en_US: 'Chicken',
        de_DE: 'Hähnchen'
    }
    ...
}
```

And with Joi I'm trying to validate like so:

```
{
   title: Joi.any().when('title', {
        is: Joi.string(),
        then: Joi.string().required(),
        otherwise: Joi.object().keys({
            en_US: Joi.string().required(),
            lt_LT: Joi.string()
        }).required()
    }),
...
}
```

However, when I try to validate I get the error `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Item cannot come after itself: title(title)`

Is there a way to use `when` with the same field?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at using [`.alternatives()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.3.0/API.md#alternatives---inherits-from-any) rather than [`.when()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.3.0/API.md#anywhencondition-options) for this situation. `.when()` is better used when the value of your key is dependant on another key's value within the same object. In your scenario, we've only got the one key to worry about.

A possible solution using `.alternatives()` could look like:

```
Joi.object().keys({
    title: Joi.alternatives(
        Joi.string(),
        Joi.object().keys({
            en_US: Joi.string().required(),
            lt_LT: Joi.string()
        })
    ).required()
})
```